# Drupal7 managed_file form

Tags: 7, forms, files

I have this managed_file form in a Drupal customized module, with this form a user can upload an image and saved it under sites/defaults/files.

```
 $form['Background_image'] = array(
'#type' => 'managed_file',
'#title' => t('Image'),
'#progress_message' => t('Please wait...'),
 '#progress_indicator' => 'bar',
'#description' => t('Click "Browse..." to select an image to upload.'),
'#required' => TRUE,
 ///'#upload_validators' => array('file_validate_extensions' => array('jpeg jpg png gif')),
'#upload_location' => 'public://backgroundimage/'
'#default_value' => $this->options['Background image'],
);
```

how to add a function to get the uploaded file? I tried this but it didnt work.

```
$image = file_load($form_state['values']['Background_image']);
```

Comment: Where are you saving the file ID after the form submits? Is this a `system_settings_form()`?

Comment: yes a system_settings_form()

Comment: What do you get for `variable_get('Background_image')`? Does it contain the expected file ID?

Comment: normaly it returns the downloaded file..but Im not sure

Comment: No it'll never return a downloaded file, only the file ID. Just run that code and see what's in it. If you get the file ID, use it with `file_load()` and you'll get the file object back. If not, just update your question because I think the scope will have shifted a bit